# How to set on executable bit for a particular file automatically

Tags: shell, vim, editors

I want that when i make create a particular file, suppose i create it in vim editor, the created file should get executable permission as well when it gets created . I want this as i am creating some python files and don't want to explicitly set permissions for the file so i want some way so that executable bit is set as soon i create a file with particular extension or with a particular editor.

Answer (score 11):

For vim, you have powerful scripting available. For example, in my .vimrc, I have:

```
" Stolen from http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/571
" Sets +x on stuff starting with the magic shebang.
au BufWritePost * if getline(1) =~ "^#!" | silent !chmod a+x <afile>
```

If you want to do it by filename only, instead of looking for the #! line, you could do:

```
au BufWritePost *.ext silent !chmod a+x <afile>     " untested
```

That [article on Debian Administration](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/571) has instructions for EMACS as well.

Comment: what is your autoread set to then?

Comment: @dustin autoread is set (true/on/yes) in my vimrc (AFAIK, its just a boolean, its either on or off)

Answer (score 2):

As much as I like [derobert's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46010/7899), it causes VIM to give me the following warning:

> W16: Warning: Mode of file "test.sh" has changed since editing started

The following (somewhat longer) code solves that problem (requires a Python-enabled vim):

```
function! SetExecutableBit()
python <<EOD
import vim
import os
import stat
filename = vim.current.buffer.name
mode = os.stat(filename).st_mode
os.chmod(filename, mode | stat.S_IXUSR)
EOD
endfunction

autocmd BufWritePost *
    \ if getline(1) =~ "^#!" | call SetExecutableBit()
```

Comment: Ah, I probably don't get that warning as I have `autoread` set.

Comment: I'm confused that silences the warning, because it seems to do the exact same thing—just calling a python script instead of chmod...

Comment: Yup. But for some reason, the Python function doesn't trigger the mode-change detection. Might be a quirk of my setup, though I believe I'm running a rather vanilla Vim on Ubuntu install.

Answer (score 0):

I came here because I wanted to automatically set on the executable bit to a binary transferred from net to a system. Is it possible? Thanks!